# "Non-existent comment" error message varying when flagging or upvoting

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, error-message

If I upvote a non-existent, this shows:

[image: Upvoting non-existent comment]

However, flagging it shows a different speech bubble:

[image: Flagging non-existent comment]

Why is this? Why can't there be one string that both conditions return?

Comment: How exactly do you upvote and flag a comment that does not exist or has been removed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think he's trying to. He's just saying the error messages don't match.

Comment: @animuson just not sure how to reproduce this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Easy enough to reproduce locally, but we don't need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this?

It's as simple as "because voting != flagging, those are two different code paths and nobody noticed this difference until now". :)

Starting with the next build, we'll show "This comment has been removed" in both cases.

Comment: Nice, changed to [meta-tag:bug] so you can status-complete it. Wow, you're quick! ;)

Comment: The world is right again. The only problem is that now I realize that text has to be repeated on different coding paths.